# ObjectBox create object entity with map and custom types

Tags: android, android-library, greendao, objectbox

How can I support object like that with `ObjectBox` lib:

```
@Entity
public class A implements Serializable {
    private Map<String, Integer> aMap;
}
```

I'm not sure if should I use [`objectBox` converter](http://objectbox.io/documentation/custom-types/)?
I found some threads which mention that `ObjectBox` have an open issues with Lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would need to use a custom type with a converter for this. Which threads do you refer to with List issues?

Comment: I would like to understand how can i save a full map<String, Integer> in one insert. Can you add a sample with converter and annotation?

Comment: Please start from the [docs on custom types](http://objectbox.io/documentation/custom-types/).

Comment: But i see in the docs that: "At the moment it is not possible to use an array with converters". So what i missed? can you add an example of a map?

Comment: Can you translate the map into some sort of string or serialized format?

Comment: I prefer not to. but its an option.

Comment: You need to do this if you do not want to reconsider the map in favor of another object.